# Kubernetes deleting statefulset deletes pod inspite of cascade=false

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am upgrading from one version of a helm chart to a newer version which fails due to changes in one of the statefulsets. My solution to this was to delete the statefulset and then upgrade. I wanted to delete the stateful set without deleting the pod so i used the `--cascade=false` argument, but regardless the pod is immediately terminated upon the statefulsets deletion.

```
kc delete --cascade=false statefulsets/trendy-grasshopper-sts
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I diagnose?

Comment: What is the output of `alias kc` and what is the output of `kubectl version`?

Comment: @imov, i had been using kubectl version 1.5.2, i updated to 1.10.3 and now the delete is working normally

Comment: thought so, glad you got it sorted